# Adding items to a cart in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am having some problems adding items to the store of Redux. I have a grid of products. These are components themselves and when I click on the plus button I want to add the product and the quantity to one if doesn't exist, and update the quantity if it does already.

Here is my component from where I dispatch.

```
const GridCard = ({ title, image, id }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

    const addToMenu = () => {
        if (quantity < 10) {
            let newQuantity = quantity + 1;
            setQuantity(newQuantity);
            if (newQuantity === 1) {
                dispatch(newProduct({
                    id,
                    quantity: 1
                }));
            } else {
                dispatch(addUnit(id))
            }
        } else {
            setQuantity(10);
        }
    };

    const removeFromMenu = () => {
        if (quantity > 0) {
            let newQuantity = quantity - 1;
            setQuantity(newQuantity);
            if (quantity === 1) {
                dispatch(removeProduct(id));
            } 
        } else {
            setQuantity(0);
        }
    };

    return (
        <SingleCard styles={{ width: "max-content" }}>
            <CardHeader title={title} />
            <img src={image} alt={title} />
            <ButtonWrapper>
                <MinusPlusButton onClick={() => removeFromMenu()}>
                    -
                </MinusPlusButton>
                <Quantity>{quantity}</Quantity>
                <MinusPlusButton onClick={() => addToMenu()}>+</MinusPlusButton>
            </ButtonWrapper>
        </SingleCard>
    );
};
```

This is the action

```
export function newProduct(userOrder) {
    return {
        type: "NEW_PRODUCT",
        userOrder,
    };
}

export function addUnit(id) {
    return {
        type: "ADD_UNIT",
        id,
    };
}
```

And here the reducer. I don't know how to get to add a new product with quantity one to the store.

```
const initialState = {
    products: []
}

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    
    if (action.type === "NEW_PRODUCT") {
        state = {
            ...state,
            products: [...state.products, action.userOrder],
        };
    }

    if (action.type === "ADD_UNIT") {
        state = {
            ...state,
            products: state.products.map((prod) =>
                prod.id === action.id
                    ? { ...prod, quantity: prod.quantity + 1 }
                    : prod
            ),
        };
    }

    console.log("Redux state", state);
    return state;
}
```

Comment: `console.log("This is the order", userOrder)` does this return the expected quantity?

Comment: Why are you incrementing the quantity both in the component _and_ the reducer?

Comment: @SakisTsalk yes, it returns the quantity

Comment: @Andy You are right, don't need to increment. My problem first is to put the action into the empty array when the product isn't in state

Comment: So you're trying to add a quantity into a product that's not in your redux state?

Comment: @SakisTsalk I solved with a workaround (see edit). I dispatch now a new action if the value is 0 that adds the object to the array of products. Probably not that elegant but it works